# How to control Music Player in iOS Device using BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, audio-player, external-accessory

I am having an hardware which acts as a peripheral and sends and receives BLE signals to my iPhone. I have integrated ANCS and is able to transfer firmware to that hardware in order to update it.

Now I want to control the music from my Hardware. I want to be able to Play, pause, next and previous functionalities through the interface of my hardware.

Which profiles do I need to implement on my hardware and what coding is required to be done on the iOS side. I am thinking it will be quite similar to ANCS profile but I am not getting a specific profile to implement this functionality.

Any suggestions are appreciated and code is a bonus welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this through BLE directly.

You will either need to implement the legacy AVRCP profile in your peripheral or install a companion app on the iOS device that can receive control events from your peripheral and issue the appropriate play/pause/skip commands via the AV framework.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to have an interface designed in order to play music in iOS Device in my iOS app. I want a functionality something like "Pebble Watch"in which the watch is able to control music on the phone just after the connection. Does this kind of functionality requires the installation of MFi program.?

Comment: Which framework then I have to use at iOS side if I implement AVRCP profile on my peripheral. As of now, I am using core-bluetooth APIs to do everything.

Comment: If you use AVRCP then you don't need to do anything - this profile is supported natively by iOS and doesn't require MFi

Comment: So, do it requires a BLE connection? As of now the watch gets connected to the iOS device through BLE.

Comment: No, this is a legacy profile, so if your peripheral's chipset can't connect in dual mode then you probably have an issue

Comment: You should be able to use the MPMusicPlayer framework to get the system music player instance and control that in response to events from your peripheral - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MPMusicPlayerController/systemMusicPlayer

Comment: As an iOS developer what do I have to do to connect with the chipset in dual mode. As of now, I am only connecting via BLE and ANCS profile is getting automatically connected.

Comment: It will depend if your chipset is capable of offering an AVRCP profile at the same time as a BLE GATT profile.  You don't need to do anything on iOS - it is the device hardware

Comment: @Paulw11: Is there any library for integrate AVRCP in iOS app. ? How can I integrate AVRCP?

Comment: What do you want to do?  You can stream audio and receive remote control events through the AV frameworks