# Is it possible to control media (play/pause/volume/...) on an iOS device remotely?

Tags: ios, libimobiledevice, mobiledevice.framework

Is it possible, with the use of libraries like libmobiledevice (or any other) to act on media controls (play/pause/volume/...) on iOS?

I am currently emulating a bluetooth keyboard to do so and I wanted to know if it was possible in another way, libmobiledevice being the closest thing I've found (working on linux even) to control an iOS device.

Comment: Can this : [How to control music player in iOS device using ble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152710/how-to-control-music-player-in-ios-device-using-ble) help you ?

Comment: You can also look at : [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/)